# Import every class/file from folder and append to list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, python-importlib

Without having to manually import every class to file, i'd like to add new classes which will all extend another class (Parent) and implement an interface.

This said, every class to import will have the same structure and functions. I'd like to append every class from the folder to a list of Parent objects.

How can that be achieved?

```
class Pig(Animal):
    __init__():
        ...
class Chicken(Animal):
    __init__():
        ...
```

I want to import both Pig and Chicken to add to a list of Animals.

Comment: Can you post sample input structure and expected output structure? Are you referring to Multiple Inheritance in Python?

Comment: You can access names of varibales in a module like `module.__all__`. You can use those names for getting variables like `getattr(module, name_of_variable)`

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL Done

Comment: So you solved it, right?

Comment: No can you post your code in context as an answer?:)

Comment: What you want to make with Chicken and Pig exactly? Do you want to add all classes which are inherited from Animal in a list? If yes, I can answer it.

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL Thats what i want yes. And if i want to add another animal (cow) in the directory where the other animals are (e.g: cow.py), i don't need to edit a single line of my code. When I restart my program, the new animal (cow) will be in the animal list.

Comment: Okey, wait a minute.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is very easy thanks to Python's interesting magics. You can find subclasses of any `cls` via `cls.__subclasses__()`.

```
from your_module import Animal

list_of_animal_subclasses = Animal.__subclasses__()
print(list_of_animal_subclasses )
```

This don't require subclasses to being in same module with Animal class nor any other thing. This gives you all submodules of `Animal` class at the moment when you call it.